# Convert Apache Arrow Table to string, the import on Table not working

Tags: reactjs, apache-arrow

I'm following this example:

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/js/

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { Table } from 'apache-arrow';

const arrow = readFileSync('simple.arrow');
const table = Table.from([arrow]);

console.log(table.toString());

/*
 foo,  bar,  baz
   1,    1,   aa
null, null, null
   3, null, null
   4,    4,  bbb
   5,    5, cccc
*/
```

and the

```
import { Table } from 'apache-arrow';
```

gives me this error:

export 'Table' (imported as 'Table') was not found in 'apache-arrow' (module has no exports)

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './io/adapters' in ...

What can I do?

Thanks!